# Analogs of Delphi types in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, delphi

What are analogues for Delphi types [**TVarType**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.TVarType) and [**OleVariant**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.OleVariant) in C/C++ ?

Comment: For those of us who don't know delphi, could you please describe what these types are.

Comment: There is no such thing as C/C++ - pick just one as the answer for C will be very different to C++

Comment: @Mark Garcia If I knew I didn't ask =)

Comment: @Myosotis, he means we want you to describe what they represent. I.e. "a signed number", "a string", "a container", or something like that.

Comment: @Myosotis SingerOfTheFall's right.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I don't know Delphi. So I am wondering what these types mean

Comment: @MarkGarcia, SingerOfTheFall - Why would he do that? Describe what they are, that is. There are clearly two links to their man pages. Last time I touched Pascal it was Turbo Pascal 6 (or was that TPW 1, I forget) The point being the required information was given, even if not read. :shrugs:

Comment: @Myosotis well that's more than weird than. What use can you take from knowing what types in C++ represent some types of the other language that you do know know? :S It's like asking how will 黒 be translated to Esperanto without knowing both, isn't it? ><

Comment: @enhzflep Don't know. :shrug: Maybe he's just learning delphi? :shrug again:

Comment: @enh, the two links were added by an edit. The OP didn't bother with finding them.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall - oh, of course - I did not look at the edit time, I feel a fool. My humble apologies... :face-palms and leaves:

Comment: @enh, lol, no worries ;)

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, Mark Garcia I need to write C++ dll for Delphi program. I have no any sources of this program. It is black box for me :) I have only an interface description which is written on Delphi %)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, clearly from their own documentation - the first is simply an unsigned word - a uint_16.

The second is a little more difficult to explain. It's basically a great big struct that contains a whole bunch of fields. This one data type includes a field for each data-type that could be transferred to/from a COM object. This means you just need to concern yourself with passing a variant to/from the object. It's then up to each of you (programmer/COM object) to extract/insert data at the relevant places.

Perhaps I shouldn't, but here's the definition for a VARIANT from oaidl.h (gcc, win32)

```
typedef struct tagVARIANT {
  _ANONYMOUS_UNION union {
    struct __tagVARIANT {
    VARTYPE vt;
    WORD wReserved1;
    WORD wReserved2;
    WORD wReserved3;
    _ANONYMOUS_UNION union {
        long lVal;
        LONGLONG llVal;
        unsigned char bVal;
        short iVal;
        float fltVal;
        double dblVal;
        VARIANT_BOOL  boolVal;
        SCODE scode;
        CY cyVal;
        DATE date;
        BSTR bstrVal;
        IUnknown *punkVal;
        LPDISPATCH pdispVal;
        SAFEARRAY *parray;
        unsigned char *pbVal;
        short *piVal;
        long *plVal;
        LONGLONG  * pllVal;
        float *pfltVal;
        double *pdblVal;
        VARIANT_BOOL *pboolVal;
        _VARIANT_BOOL  *pbool;
        SCODE *pscode;
        CY *pcyVal;
        DATE *pdate;
        BSTR *pbstrVal;
        IUnknown **ppunkVal;
        LPDISPATCH *ppdispVal;
        SAFEARRAY **pparray;
        struct tagVARIANT *pvarVal;
        void *byref;
        CHAR cVal;
        USHORT uiVal;
        ULONG ulVal;
        ULONGLONG ullVal;
        INT intVal;
        UINT uintVal;
        DECIMAL *pdecVal;
        CHAR  *pcVal;
        USHORT  *puiVal;
        ULONG  *pulVal;
        ULONGLONG * pullVal;
        INT  *pintVal;
        UINT  *puintVal;
        _ANONYMOUS_STRUCT struct {
            PVOID pvRecord;
            struct IRecordInfo *pRecInfo;
        } __VARIANT_NAME_4;
    } __VARIANT_NAME_3;
    } __VARIANT_NAME_2;
    DECIMAL decVal;
  } __VARIANT_NAME_1;
} VARIANT,*LPVARIANT;
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  You should have and you did.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent of `OleVariant` is [VARIANT structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is wrapped in [_variant_t Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Visual C++.

The equivalent of `TVarType` is [VARTYPE typedef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), technically, it is unsigned short, but it holds values of [VARENUM enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221170%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++Builder specifically, it has its own `TVarType` and `OleVariant` types that directly correlate with those Delphi types.  `TVarType` is declared in System.hpp, and `OleVariant` is declared in systvari.h, just like the documentation you linked to says.